# How to create json with keys as array values

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

For example, I got an `array = [zoo, foo, bar, ...]`.

I need to create json with hash, where keys is array's values, and hash's values is another hashes
Something like this:

```
"model_field": {
   "zoo": {
      "name": "zoo",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
   },
   "foo": {
      "name": "foo",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
   },
  ...
}
```

I tried to do something like this

```
def json
  render json: {model_field: {array.each do |x|
      {x => {name: x, key2: "value2", key3: "value3"}
      }
    end
    }
  }
end
```

but than i'm stuck. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: @SebastianPalma array is input. And i got a table in my show view. I need access to values in that json in my view.

Comment: `%i[zoo foo bar].zip([{key: 42}] * 3).to_h.each { |k, h| h[:name] = k }`

Answer (score 0):

`each` returns the object you iterated on, no matter what you did inside the loop:

```
%w[zoo foo bar].each { |x|  } # => ["zoo", "foo", "bar"]
```

Something you could do is `each_with_object` to pass a hash to each iteration and fill it. This returns the object you passed in, after the final iteration:

```
array = %w[zoo foo bar]

output = {
  model_field: array.each_with_object({}) do |x, hash|
    hash[x] = { name: x, key2: rand(1..100) }
  end
}
# => {
#      :model_field=>{
#        "zoo"=>{:name=>"zoo", :key2=>25},
#        "foo"=>{:name=>"foo", :key2=>83},
#        "bar"=>{:name=>"bar", :key2=>98}
#      }
#    }
```